# How to show the answer once the answer is over 2 decimal places

Tags: .net, vb.net, number-formatting

I have a Visual Basic calculator that calculates the volume of a cone.

I have two answers, one in mm cube and the other in meters cubed (which is rounded to nearest hundredth (2 decimal places)). But I only want to show the meters cubed once it reaches 0.01 or higher.

Here is my calculation code

```
Private Sub txtSidea_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtHeight.Leave, txtRadius.Leave
    'calculate volume cubic mm using V= 1/3 pi R*2*H  
    Const PI As Double = System.Math.PI
    lbAnswerlVolumeMM.Text = (1 / 3 * PI * ((Val(txtRadius.Text) ^ 2) * Val(txtHeight.Text))).ToString("#") + " :Cuibic mm"
    'calculate volume cubic meter using V= 1/3 pi R*2*H / 10^9
    lblAnswerVolumeMetres.Text = ((1 / 3 * PI * ((Val(txtRadius.Text) ^ 2) * Val(txtHeight.Text))) / 10 ^ 9).ToString("#.##") + " :Cubic Metre"
End Sub
```

An example would be; Height 50mm and radius 30mm. which would output 47124 mm cube which is good. But it displays nothing for the metres cube, So if the answer is under 0.01 for metres cube i would like it to hide the label until it was over 0.01 and then display the result.

Comment: Please share sample Input and Output

Comment: Maybe check if the value is above 0.01 or below 0.01 and use a different calculation based on that?

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines as

Comment: Private Sub lblAnswerVolumeMetres(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblAnswerVolumeMetres
        If lblAnswerVolumeMetres < 0.01 Then lblAnswerVolumeMetres = ""
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: An example would be; Height 50mm and radius 30mm. which would output 47124 mm cube which is good. But it displays nothing for the metres cube, So if the answer is under 0.01 for metres cube i would like it to hide the label until it was over 0.01 and then display the result.

Answer (score 0):

TRy this:

```
Private Sub txtSidea_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtHeight.Leave, txtRadius.Leave
    'calculate volume cubic mm using V= 1/3 pi R*2*H  
    Const PI As Double = System.Math.PI
    lbAnswerlVolumeMM.Text = (1 / 3 * PI * ((Val(txtRadius.Text) ^ 2) * Val(txtHeight.Text))).ToString("#")
    'calculate volume cubic meter using V= 1/3 pi R*2*H / 10^9
    lblAnswerVolumeMetres.Text = ((1 / 3 * PI * ((Val(txtRadius.Text) ^ 2) * Val(txtHeight.Text))) / 10 ^ 9).ToString("#.##")

    '--Decide which to hide
    If lblAnswerVolumeMetres.Text >= 0.01 then
        lblAnswerVolumeMetres.Visible = True
        lbAnswerlVolumeMM.Visible = False
    Else
        lblAnswerVolumeMetres.Visible = False
        lbAnswerlVolumeMM.Visible = True
    End If
    '--Shift the description to after the decision is made based on the number.
    lblAnswerVolumeMetres.Text &= " :Cubic mm"
    lbAnswerlVolumeMM &= " :Cubic Metre"
End Sub
```

Comment: It works but when i type my number into txtSidea i get this error. Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Comment: make sure you copy the code as-is (ie, don't add the "cubic " text at the top part where you calculate the volume answer.  It should work. If it works, please mark as answer.